# Diagonal Side div color css js

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have 2 `div` like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.container {
    width:100%;
}


.one , .two {
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I want to give this 2 divs a diagonal side color to be like this

[image]

I tried `rotate` but it gave me some white spot.
Can any one help me please ?

Comment: You only need to rotate one  div above the other. Can you provide the code you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use clip paths and 2 div within a container,

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOXPmv

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #111;
}

#left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 101%; /* If you make it 100%, you get a bit of black showing along the diagonal */
  height: 100%;
  background: #99b4d3;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 76% 0, 24% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 76% 0, 24% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #d9b596;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(76% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 24% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(76% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 24% 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A single gradient on the parent will do the visual:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(140deg, rgb(153, 180, 211)50%, rgb(217, 181, 150) 50%)
}
```

```html
example on HTML background sized at 100% viewport's height at the minimum.
```

Comment: This one is simple and easy to remember , Thank you

Comment: @Zak-Dev to add content over it, you can play around with skew and content sliced in small bits https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aVZzLd

Answer (score 2):

Try using an svg path css background property.  See example below.

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  height: 117px;
}

.one {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 117px;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='100%' viewBox='0 0 100 100' fill='blue' preserveAspectRatio='none'><path d='M0 0 L0 100 L50 100 L100 0 Z' /></svg>") no-repeat;
}
.two {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 117px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```